# How to fix my circular background for my CDN fontawesome icons

Tags: html, css

So I searched up a simple circular background for my icon and tried to scale it to how I wanted it but got an issue shown here

[image]

As you can see the headers like Address is pushed down and the icons dont fit in the backgrounds

This is what I'm looking for but with white backgrounds on the icons of course

[image]

Here is my code

### DEMO:

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

html {
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 999;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 117rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 1.5rem;
}

.menu-icons {
  color: #eee;
  font-size: 4rem;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 2rem;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 1500;
  display: none;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 8rem;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(225, 225, 225, 0.1);
}

.logo {
  display: flex;
  margin-right: 5rem;
}

.nav-list {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  align-items: center;
}

.nav-list li {
  line-height: 8rem;
  position: relative;
}

.sub-menu li {
  line-height: 4rem;
}

.nav-list a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  background-color: #1e90ff;
  padding: 0 1.5rem;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  transition: color 650ms;
  transition: background-color 650ms;
}

.nav-list a:hover {
  color: black;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.cart {
  height: 30px;
  width: 40px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-right: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.btn {
  padding: 1.3rem;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #1e90ff;
  border: 2px solid #1e90ff;
  border-radius: 5rem;
  transition: background-color 650ms;
}

.btn:hover {
  color: black;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.sub-menu {
  width: 20rem;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  border-top: 3px solid #00bfff;
  z-index: 100;
  top: 16rem;
  transition: all 650ms ease;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.sub-menu::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -2.5rem;
  left: 3rem;
  border: 1.2rem solid transparent;
  border-bottom-color: #00bfff;
}

.sub-menu .sub-menu::before {
  top: 0.9rem;
  left: -2.5rem;
  border: 1.2rem solid transparent;
  border-right-color: #00bfff;
}

.sub-menu .sub-menu {
  border-top: none;
  border-left: 3px solid #00bfff;
  top: 0;
  left: 160%;
}

.nav-list li:hover > .sub-menu {
  top: 8rem;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}

.sub-menu li:hover > .sub-menu {
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
}

li.move-right {
  margin: auto 0 auto auto;
  line-height: initial;
  transition: color 650ms;
  transition: background-color 650ms;
}

.slide-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 25vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 5px solid #1e90ff;
  box-shadow: 0 16px 32px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2),
    0 10px 30px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}

.slide-container .slider {
  width: 500%;
  height: 100%;
  /* animation: animate 30s linear infinite; */
}

.slide-container .slider .slide {
  width: 20%;
  height: 100%;
}

.slide-container .slider .slide .caption {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 97%;
  height: 90%;
  padding: 10px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.slide-container .slider .slide .caption h2 {
  padding: 0;
  color: white;
  font-size: 4em;
}

.slide-container .slider .slide .caption p {
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
  .nav-list {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100vh;
    display: none;
    align-items: initial;
    flex-direction: column;
    background-color: #1e90ff;
    z-index: 1000;
    overflow-y: scroll;
  }

  .nav-list li {
    line-height: 6rem;
  }

  .sub-menu {
    position: initial;
    border: 3px solid transparent;
    border-left-color: #00bfff;
    margin-left: 1rem;
    max-height: 0;
  }

  .sub-menu::before {
    display: none;
  }

  .nav-list li:hover > .sub-menu {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
    max-height: initial;
  }

  li.move-right {
    margin: 0 auto 0 0;
    line-height: initial;
  }

  .menu-icons {
    display: block;
  }

  .fas fa-times {
    display: none;
  }

  nav.active .fas fa-times {
    display: block;
  }

  nav.active .fas fa-bars {
    display: none;
  }

  nav.active .nav-list {
    display: flex;
  }
}

.hero-container {
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)),
    url(../images/heroImage.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

.hero-container span {
  color: white;
  font-size: 50px;
  letter-spacing: 0.2em;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border: 10px solid white;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 3px 14px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.hero-container a {
  padding: 15px 16px;
  color: white;
  background-color: #1e90ff;
  height: 15px;
  border-radius: 5rem;
  transition: background-color 650ms;
}

.hero-btn:hover {
  color: black;
  background-color: yellow;
  transition: background-color 650ms;
}

.slide-container .slider .slide.business1 {
  background: url(../images/business1.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

.slide-container .slider .slide.business2 {
  background: url(../images/business2.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

.slide-container .slider .slide.business3 {
  background: url(../images/business3.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

.slide-container .slider .slide.business4 {
  background: url(../images/business4.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

.slide-container .slider .slide.canvas1 {
  background: url(../images/canvas1.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

.slide-container .slider .slide.canvas2 {
  background: url(../images/canvas2.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

.slide-container .slider .slide.canvas3 {
  background: url(../images/canvas3.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

.slide-container .slider .slide.canvas4 {
  background: url(../images/canvas4.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

.slide-container .slider .slide.embroidery1 {
  background: url(../images/embroidery1.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

.slide-container .slider .slide.embroidery2 {
  background: url(../images/embroidery2.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

.slide-container .slider .slide.embroidery3 {
  background: url(../images/embroidery3.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

.slide-container .slider .slide.embroidery4 {
  background: url(../images/embroidery4.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

.slide-container .slider .slide.engraving1 {
  background: url(../images/engraving1.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

.slide-container .slider .slide.engraving2 {
  background: url(../images/engraving1.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

.slide-container .slider .slide.engraving3 {
  background: url(../images/engraving1.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

.slide-container .slider .slide.engraving4 {
  background: url(../images/engraving1.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

.slide-container .slider .slide.signs1 {
  background: url(../images/signs1.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

.slide-container .slider .slide.signs2 {
  background: url(../images/signs1.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

.slide-container .slider .slide.signs3 {
  background: url(../images/signs1.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

.slide-container .slider .slide.signs4 {
  background: url(../images/signs1.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

.slide-container .slider .slide.apperal1 {
  background: url(../images/apperal1.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

.slide-container .slider .slide.apperal2 {
  background: url(../images/apperal1.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

.slide-container .slider .slide.apperal3 {
  background: url(../images/apperal1.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

.slide-container .slider .slide.apperal4 {
  background: url(../images/apperal1.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}


@keyframes animate {
  0% {
    left: 0;
  }

  20% {
    left: 0;
  }

  25% {
    left: -100%;
  }

  45% {
    left: -100%;
  }
  50% {
    left: -200%;
  }
  70% {
    left: -200%;
  }
  75% {
    left: -300%;
  }
  95% {
    left: -300%;
  }
  100% {
    left: -400%;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
}

.slide-btn {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 5rem;
  border: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  background-color: white;
  transition: background-color 650ms;
}

.slide-btn:hover {
  background-color: #1e90ff;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: background-color 650ms;
}

.footer-row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.footer {
  background-color: #1e90ff;
  padding: 70px 0;
}

.footer-container {
  max-width: 1170px;
  margin: auto;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
}

.footer-col {
  width: 25%;
  padding: 0 15px;
}

.footer-col h4 {
  font-size: 18px;
  color: white;
  text-transform: capatalize;
  margin-bottom: 35px;
  font-weight: 500;
  position: relative;
}

.footer-col h4::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: -10px;
  background-color: white;
  height: 2px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 50px;
}

.footer-col ul li:not(:last-child) {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.footer-col ul li a {
  font-size: 16px;
  text-transform: capatalize;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: white;
  display: block;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.footer-col ul li a:hover {
  color: yellow;
  padding-left: 8px;
}

.footer-col .social-links {
  display: inline-block;
  /* height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.2);*/
  margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 40px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: white;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.footer-col .social-links:hover {
  color: yellow;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .footer-col {
    width: 50%;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 574px) {
  .footer-col {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .slide-container .slider .slide .caption h2 {
    font-size: 3em;
  }
  .slide-container .slider .slide .caption p {
    font-size: 1.2em;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-height: 400px) {
  .slide-container .slider .slide .caption {
    padding-top: 2px;
  }
  .slide-container .slider .slide .caption h2 {
  padding: 0;
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

.slide-container .slider .slide .caption p {
  color: white;
  font-size: 1em;
}
.hero-btn {
    position: relative;
    top:-40px;
    width: 100%;
  }
}

.hero-container h2 {
  color: white;
  font-size: 50px;
  letter-spacing: 0.2em;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 3px 14px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  
}

.back-container {
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)),
    url(../images/heroImage.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}


.formContainer {
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 20px;
    
}


.formText {
    color: black;
    border-top: none;
    border-left: none;
    border-right: none;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #1e90ff;
    padding: 20px 45px 20px;
}

.formContent {
    margin-top: 5px;

}

input[type=text] {
  font-size: 20px;
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
  width: 250px;
  height: 50px;
}

.info {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.info h1 {
    color: #1e90ff;
}

.info h2 {
    color: white;
}

.icons {
    background: white;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 50px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding: 30px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.3/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-SZXxX4whJ79/gErwcOYf+zWLeJdY/qpuqC4cAa9rOGUstPomtqpuNWT9wdPEn2fk" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!--<?php include ('header.php') ?>-->

<div class="back-container">
    <div class="info" style="float: left; padding: 150px;">
        <div class="icons">
            <i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt fa-3x"></i>
            <h1 style="display: inline-block;">Address:</h1>
        </div>
        <h2>75 Route 80, Dildo, NL, Canada</h2>
        <div class="icons">
            <i class="fas fa-phone-alt fa-3x"></i>
            <h1 style="display: inline-block;">Phone:</h1>
        </div>
        <h2>(709) 582-4566</h2>
        <div class="icons">
            <i class="fas fa-phone-alt fa-3x"></i>
            <h1 style="display: inline-block;">Fax:</h1>
        </div>
        <h2>(709) 582-4567</h2>
        <div class="icons">
            <i class="fas fa-envelope fa-3x"></i>
            <h1 style="display: inline-block;">Email:</h1>
        </div>
        <h2>info@activeprinting.ca</h2>
        <div class="icons">
            <i class="fas fa-mail-bulk fa-3x"></i>
            <h1 style="display: inline-block;">P.O Box:</h1>
        </div>
        <h2>P.O Box 352</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="formContainer">
        <form>
            <div class="formText">
                <h1>Name:</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="formContent">
                <input type="text" name="name" required="required">
            </div>
            <div class="formText">
                <h1>Email:</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="formContent">
                <input type="text" name="email" required="required">
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- 
<?php include('footer.php') ?> -->
```

My classes for the forms and icons are on the bottom.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your selector to `> i` to affect children

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

html {
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 999;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 117rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 1.5rem;
}

.menu-icons {
  color: #eee;
  font-size: 4rem;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 2rem;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 1500;
  display: none;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 8rem;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(225, 225, 225, 0.1);
}

.logo {
  display: flex;
  margin-right: 5rem;
}

.nav-list {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  align-items: center;
}

.nav-list li {
  line-height: 8rem;
  position: relative;
}

.sub-menu li {
  line-height: 4rem;
}

.nav-list a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  background-color: #1e90ff;
  padding: 0 1.5rem;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  transition: color 650ms;
  transition: background-color 650ms;
}

.nav-list a:hover {
  color: black;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.cart {
  height: 30px;
  width: 40px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-right: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.btn {
  padding: 1.3rem;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #1e90ff;
  border: 2px solid #1e90ff;
  border-radius: 5rem;
  transition: background-color 650ms;
}

.btn:hover {
  color: black;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.sub-menu {
  width: 20rem;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  border-top: 3px solid #00bfff;
  z-index: 100;
  top: 16rem;
  transition: all 650ms ease;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.sub-menu::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -2.5rem;
  left: 3rem;
  border: 1.2rem solid transparent;
  border-bottom-color: #00bfff;
}

.sub-menu .sub-menu::before {
  top: 0.9rem;
  left: -2.5rem;
  border: 1.2rem solid transparent;
  border-right-color: #00bfff;
}

.sub-menu .sub-menu {
  border-top: none;
  border-left: 3px solid #00bfff;
  top: 0;
  left: 160%;
}

.nav-list li:hover>.sub-menu {
  top: 8rem;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}

.sub-menu li:hover>.sub-menu {
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
}

li.move-right {
  margin: auto 0 auto auto;
  line-height: initial;
  transition: color 650ms;
  transition: background-color 650ms;
}

.slide-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 25vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 5px solid #1e90ff;
  box-shadow: 0 16px 32px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 10px 30px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}

.slide-container .slider {
  width: 500%;
  height: 100%;
  /* animation: animate 30s linear infinite; */
}

.slide-container .slider .slide {
  width: 20%;
  height: 100%;
}

.slide-container .slider .slide .caption {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 97%;
  height: 90%;
  padding: 10px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.slide-container .slider .slide .caption h2 {
  padding: 0;
  color: white;
  font-size: 4em;
}

.slide-container .slider .slide .caption p {
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
  .nav-list {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100vh;
    display: none;
    align-items: initial;
    flex-direction: column;
    background-color: #1e90ff;
    z-index: 1000;
    overflow-y: scroll;
  }
  .nav-list li {
    line-height: 6rem;
  }
  .sub-menu {
    position: initial;
    border: 3px solid transparent;
    border-left-color: #00bfff;
    margin-left: 1rem;
    max-height: 0;
  }
  .sub-menu::before {
    display: none;
  }
  .nav-list li:hover>.sub-menu {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
    max-height: initial;
  }
  li.move-right {
    margin: 0 auto 0 0;
    line-height: initial;
  }
  .menu-icons {
    display: block;
  }
  .fas fa-times {
    display: none;
  }
  nav.active .fas fa-times {
    display: block;
  }
  nav.active .fas fa-bars {
    display: none;
  }
  nav.active .nav-list {
    display: flex;
  }
}

.hero-container {
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)), url(../images/heroImage.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

.hero-container span {
  color: white;
  font-size: 50px;
  letter-spacing: 0.2em;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border: 10px solid white;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 3px 14px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.hero-container a {
  padding: 15px 16px;
  color: white;
  background-color: #1e90ff;
  height: 15px;
  border-radius: 5rem;
  transition: background-color 650ms;
}

.hero-btn:hover {
  color: black;
  background-color: yellow;
  transition: background-color 650ms;
}

.slide-container .slider .slide.business1 {
  background: url(../images/business1.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

.slide-container .slider .slide.business2 {
  background: url(../images/business2.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

.slide-container .slider .slide.business3 {
  background: url(../images/business3.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

.slide-container .slider .slide.business4 {
  background: url(../images/business4.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

.slide-container .slider .slide.canvas1 {
  background: url(../images/canvas1.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

.slide-container .slider .slide.canvas2 {
  background: url(../images/canvas2.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

.slide-container .slider .slide.canvas3 {
  background: url(../images/canvas3.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

.slide-container .slider .slide.canvas4 {
  background: url(../images/canvas4.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

.slide-container .slider .slide.embroidery1 {
  background: url(../images/embroidery1.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

.slide-container .slider .slide.embroidery2 {
  background: url(../images/embroidery2.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

.slide-container .slider .slide.embroidery3 {
  background: url(../images/embroidery3.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

.slide-container .slider .slide.embroidery4 {
  background: url(../images/embroidery4.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

.slide-container .slider .slide.engraving1 {
  background: url(../images/engraving1.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

.slide-container .slider .slide.engraving2 {
  background: url(../images/engraving1.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

.slide-container .slider .slide.engraving3 {
  background: url(../images/engraving1.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

.slide-container .slider .slide.engraving4 {
  background: url(../images/engraving1.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

.slide-container .slider .slide.signs1 {
  background: url(../images/signs1.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

.slide-container .slider .slide.signs2 {
  background: url(../images/signs1.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

.slide-container .slider .slide.signs3 {
  background: url(../images/signs1.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

.slide-container .slider .slide.signs4 {
  background: url(../images/signs1.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

.slide-container .slider .slide.apperal1 {
  background: url(../images/apperal1.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

.slide-container .slider .slide.apperal2 {
  background: url(../images/apperal1.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

.slide-container .slider .slide.apperal3 {
  background: url(../images/apperal1.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

.slide-container .slider .slide.apperal4 {
  background: url(../images/apperal1.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

@keyframes animate {
  0% {
    left: 0;
  }
  20% {
    left: 0;
  }
  25% {
    left: -100%;
  }
  45% {
    left: -100%;
  }
  50% {
    left: -200%;
  }
  70% {
    left: -200%;
  }
  75% {
    left: -300%;
  }
  95% {
    left: -300%;
  }
  100% {
    left: -400%;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {}

.slide-btn {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 5rem;
  border: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  background-color: white;
  transition: background-color 650ms;
}

.slide-btn:hover {
  background-color: #1e90ff;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: background-color 650ms;
}

.footer-row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.footer {
  background-color: #1e90ff;
  padding: 70px 0;
}

.footer-container {
  max-width: 1170px;
  margin: auto;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
}

.footer-col {
  width: 25%;
  padding: 0 15px;
}

.footer-col h4 {
  font-size: 18px;
  color: white;
  text-transform: capatalize;
  margin-bottom: 35px;
  font-weight: 500;
  position: relative;
}

.footer-col h4::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: -10px;
  background-color: white;
  height: 2px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 50px;
}

.footer-col ul li:not(:last-child) {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.footer-col ul li a {
  font-size: 16px;
  text-transform: capatalize;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: white;
  display: block;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.footer-col ul li a:hover {
  color: yellow;
  padding-left: 8px;
}

.footer-col .social-links {
  display: inline-block;
  /* height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.2);*/
  margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 40px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: white;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.footer-col .social-links:hover {
  color: yellow;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .footer-col {
    width: 50%;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 574px) {
  .footer-col {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .slide-container .slider .slide .caption h2 {
    font-size: 3em;
  }
  .slide-container .slider .slide .caption p {
    font-size: 1.2em;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-height: 400px) {
  .slide-container .slider .slide .caption {
    padding-top: 2px;
  }
  .slide-container .slider .slide .caption h2 {
    padding: 0;
    color: white;
    font-size: 1.5em;
  }
  .slide-container .slider .slide .caption p {
    color: white;
    font-size: 1em;
  }
  .hero-btn {
    position: relative;
    top: -40px;
    width: 100%;
  }
}

.hero-container h2 {
  color: white;
  font-size: 50px;
  letter-spacing: 0.2em;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 3px 14px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.back-container {
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)), url(../images/heroImage.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.formContainer {
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 20px;
}

.formText {
  color: black;
  border-top: none;
  border-left: none;
  border-right: none;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #1e90ff;
  padding: 20px 45px 20px;
}

.formContent {
  margin-top: 5px;
}

input[type=text] {
  font-size: 20px;
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
  width: 250px;
  height: 50px;
}

.info {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.info h1 {
  color: #1e90ff;
}

.info h2 {
  color: white;
}

.icons {
  /*    background: white;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 30px;*/
}

.icons {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
}
.icons>i {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  background: white;
  padding: 30px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.3/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-SZXxX4whJ79/gErwcOYf+zWLeJdY/qpuqC4cAa9rOGUstPomtqpuNWT9wdPEn2fk" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="back-container">
  <div class="info" style="float: left; padding: 150px;">
    <div class="icons">
      <i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt fa-3x"></i>
      <h1 style="display: inline-block;">Address:</h1>
    </div>
    <h2>75 Route 80, Dildo, NL, Canada</h2>
    <div class="icons">
      <i class="fas fa-phone-alt fa-3x"></i>
      <h1 style="display: inline-block;">Phone:</h1>
    </div>
    <h2>(709) 582-4566</h2>
    <div class="icons">
      <i class="fas fa-phone-alt fa-3x"></i>
      <h1 style="display: inline-block;">Fax:</h1>
    </div>
    <h2>(709) 582-4567</h2>
    <div class="icons">
      <i class="fas fa-envelope fa-3x"></i>
      <h1 style="display: inline-block;">Email:</h1>
    </div>
    <h2>info@activeprinting.ca</h2>
    <div class="icons">
      <i class="fas fa-mail-bulk fa-3x"></i>
      <h1 style="display: inline-block;">P.O Box:</h1>
    </div>
    <h2>P.O Box 352</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="formContainer">
    <form>
      <div class="formText">
        <h1>Name:</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="formContent">
        <input type="text" name="name" required="required">
      </div>
      <div class="formText">
        <h1>Email:</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="formContent">
        <input type="text" name="email" required="required">
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That does get what I want, but what if I was looking for the blue text like 'Address' for it to be beside the map logo

Comment: I édited it is that what you are looking for ?

Answer (score 0):

```
.icons i::before{
  height:100%;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
}
.icons i{
  background:white;
  padding:10px;
  height:70px;
  width:70px;
  border-radius:50%;
  
}
```

add this to your code

and remove

```
.icons {
    background: white;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 50px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding: 30px;
}
```

from css